# Graph Theory - Can a path branch/split/fork?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Given the graph:

### [image: Graph]

With nodes:

```
A, B, C, D.
```

and Edges:

```
A->B, A->C, B->C, B->D, C->D
```

A path is (under my understanding) a sequence of edges that connect vertices together.
An simple path would be A->B, B->C, C->D.
Is it possible to have a path that has a branch/fork/split? 
Example:

```
A->B, B->C, B->D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not permitted. The standard definition of a path is a series of one or more nodes v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub> such that for any two consecutive nodes in the path, there's an edge from the first node to the second. That would rule out the sort of object that you're talking about from being a path.

That's not to say that what you're looking at isn't interesting or couldn't be studied, though. There may be some other definition that captures what you're looking for.